# What are the Names of the People in a Quest?

Tags: nouns

In business there is an employer who pays an employee to work.

In quests, what is the word for the person who issues the quest? And what is the name of the person who goes on the quest? (Questor perhaps?)

Comment: It's usually in the nature of an *employer* that he spends quite a bit of his time employing many different people, and the fact of him having that relationship with his employees is fairly important to him, them, and the world at large. A few kings in nursery stories send their sons out on quests, but it's not sufficiently common that we're likely to need a word to reference *a person whose social role/identity is aptly summarized as "issuer of quests"*.

Comment: I don't think you issue a quest, rather an _order_; and you _go on/set out_ on a quest _to/in order to_ - it's a _search_. People in authority give out orders which others follow; otherwise such people as _adventurers_ etc. may have their own motivations and agendas.

Comment: As for the person who issues the quest, the word _sponsor_ could work, particularly if the sponsor is funding the quest or expedition. As an example, the Encyclopædia Britannica mentions, "Columbus made his transatlantic voyages under the [sponsorship](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/127070/Christopher-Columbus) of Ferdinand II and Isabella I."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many words that you could use, given more context about the nature of the quest, such as *suitor*, *knight*, *warrior*, *wanderer*, etc.

The most general hypernyms I can think of are **hero** and **inquisitor** (because a quest is a long or arduous search).

> **Hero**. n. a person, typically a man, who is admired or idealized for
>   courage, outstanding achievements, or noble qualities.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20hero&oq=define%20hero&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.991j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8)

> **Inquisitor** n. a person making an inquiry, especially one seen to be excessively harsh or searching.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&espv=2&q=define%20inquisitor&oq=define%20inquisitor&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0i10j0l2j0i10l2j0i22i30l4.3600.749018.0.749114.20.19.0.0.0.0.363.2080.5j10j0j1.16.0.msedr.2..0...1.1.64.serp..7.13.1598.0.Xh_RyeZ3e0I)

**Edit:**

The "employer" could be referred to as the *quest master* or *dispatcher*. If you want to get fancy you could use a metonym, such as the *hand/sword of the quest*. Also, though it is somewhat cliché, I think *lord* or *quest lord* may have some relevance here.

> **Lord**. n. act in a superior and domineering manner toward (someone).

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20lord&oq=define%20lord)

Comment: I do actually like your "hand/sword of the quest", independent of cliché-ness.

Answer (score 1):

There is the term  [quester](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quester) to indicate a person engaged in a quest:

> - someone making a search or inquiry; (AHD).

(The Free Dictionary)

> - explorer, *the quester writes his own journey, always poised at the moment of articulating two worlds,* the one of disappointment which he leaves behind and the one of promise he travels towards. As Nicholas Birns concludes, 'Both in ...

([Subverting the Empire: Explorers and Exploration in Australian Fiction](https://books.google.it/books?id=LI7-ilKlpxwC&pg=PA193&dq=%22quester%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=voYiVd3HEcXvarLCgdgM&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=%22quester%22&f=false)
)

Comment: Even *that* one is a bit "off the beaten track" in terms of normal usage. But OP is specifically asking for a word to reference the (other) person who actually *charges* the quester with his quest (and would you believe it? - Google Chrome's spellchecker underlines even ***quester***, so I don't suppose it'll think much of OP's tentative ***questor*** :)

Comment: @Josh61 I think this is my favorite as it is intuitively obvious what the individuals identity is with relation to the quest. I also see this defined in Dictionary.com: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quest but not in Merriam-Webster :( However this is an incomplete answer because there is no word for the person who issues the quest...

Comment: @JonathanMee - I don't think that there is a *quest* word to indicate who issues the quest. I'd notice that in the case of the *quester* they may coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the quest, you'd usually refer to them as:

**Explorers/archeologists/pilgrims/detectives/mercenaries/assassins**, etc.

The person initiating the quest is called ***"The Bankroller"***. (US)